# How to identify capital and lower case word in TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We need somehow to differentiate between ALL CAPITAL LETTER WORD vs Title word for instance:

```
[Column 1]
Kenya
MELBOURNE
Japan
SYDNEY
CANBERRA
WOLLONGONG
United States
United Kingdoms
```

The capital words mean cities and the title words mean country.

We've been looking others columns to differentiate these things but this is affective one that we can come up with.

Comment: Um. Not to be a jerk, but why the heck would you use case to determine what a word means? Add a column or store them in different tables :p

Comment: We are only analysing the data. It's come up like that originally. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wow, what an awful way to differentiate between two different types of facts.

Anyway you can perform a case-sensitive comparison by changing the column to be case sensitive, or using the `COLLATE` clause on each comparison:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(c VARCHAR(255));

INSERT @x VALUES
('Kenya'),
('MELBOURNE'),
('Japan'),
('SYDNEY'),
('CANBERRA'),
('WOLLONGONG'),
('United States'),
('United Kingdom');

SELECT city = CASE 
  WHEN c = UPPER(c) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN 
    THEN c ELSE NULL END,
  country = CASE
  WHEN c <> UPPER(c) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN 
    THEN c ELSE NULL END
FROM @x;
```

Results:

```
city         country
----------   --------------
NULL         Kenya           
MELBOURNE    NULL
NULL         Japan           
SYDNEY       NULL
CANBERRA     NULL
WOLLONGONG   NULL
NULL         United States   
NULL         United Kingdom
```

Answer (score 1):

to identify the cities, check that the text is the same as it's [`UPPER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180055.aspx) value:

```
select * from table 
where [Column 1] = UPPER([Column 1]) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI
```

Note that, as Aaron Bertrand correctly points out, this is dependent on collation.

Comment: If collation is case insensitive, SQL Server will consider them identical.

Comment: I think it does consider them identical. He will likely need to write a function for this.